# Remove all nonnumeric characters from a cell in Excel (no VBA)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to have one cell that has date in the format 12-AUG-1984 and another cell in another sheet of the same workbook convert to ONLY two things (please show me how to do both using Excel):

1) Remove the two hypens
2) convert the date to all numbers where even Aug (August) becomes 08 so it'll be 12081984

I tried to find other questions that answer this but they seem to be either in VBA or some other code. I'm very much a novice so VBA is a bit of a problem.

Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one for *`Remove the two hypens`*:

```
=TEXT(A1,"ddmmmyyyy")
```

and this one for *`convert the date to all numbers where even Aug (August) becomes 08`*:

```
=TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy")
```

Comment: If you want it as a number then `=VALUE(TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy"))`

Comment: It's a vicious circle:) if you apply `VALUE` to text, you'd get result as 41871 and you have to apply a custom format to cell like `ddmmmyyy`:)

Comment: Nope Value will format the generated text string as a number given `A1 = 12/31/2013` `=VALUE(TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy"))` will generate a number based on the formated string so `31122013`

Comment: sorry, you're right, works for `=TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy")` (I've accidentally tested `=TEXT(A1,"ddmmmyyyy")` with `mmm` - which is obviously not working)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the response. =VALUE(TEXT(A1,"ddmmyyyy")) works great. One thing I forgot is that users will be able to enter date in the different formats they're used to within the 12AUG1984 such as: 1) 12-AUG-84
2)12.AUG.1984
3)12/AUG/1984
4)12AUG1984. You're code worked great for all the 4 above except #2. Is there a reason the period '.' is preventing the formula from working? Thank you.

Comment: @user3461278, I don't have any issue with all your examples. If your dates stored as text, you can try: `=VALUE(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),"ddmmyyyy"))`

Comment: @user3461278 @simoco is correct the `.` means it is not a truly formatted `date` according to `excel` so you remove the period for excel to try and format correctly.

Comment: @engineersmnky and simco Thank you both VERY much! Works for all date styles now.